# Sudden Error in '': free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++, linux, qt, pointers, libgc

I am having this segmentation fault after a colleague of mine committed some new features on our project. The new feature has no impact on the following function, but only increases the QString argument size.
After some debugging, I've figured out that segmentation fault was happening after the following function return.

I need to know why does it is happening and why my workaround worked, and if the workaround is safe?

I must say that the following snippet it is working on older version of Qt (5.3.1 with gcc 4.8) that I have now installed (Qt 5.9 with gcc 7.0).
It also works nicely on Debug rather that Release compiling mode on Qt.

Finally, I don't want to discuss the effectiveness of this encryption method, but the entitled problem.

The crashes happens immediately after function returning, I have no idea why.

```
QString Utility::encrypt(QString text)
{
    QByteArray textUtf8 = text.toUtf8();

    // Convert QString to Char
    const char *srcString = textUtf8.constData();
    char encrypted[ textUtf8.size() ];

    // Copy Char by Char
    strcpy(encrypted,srcString);
    for(int u=0; u<textUtf8.size(); u++ ){
        encrypted[u]++;
    }

    return QString::fromUtf8(encrypted);
}
```

The output from Segmentation fault is:

```
*** Error in `/home/user/workspace/build-swFree-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_GCC_64bit-Release/swFree': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001cfc800 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7eff199067e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7eff1990f37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7eff1991353c]
/home/user/workspace/build-swFree-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_GCC_64bit-Release/swFree[0x40171f]
/home/user/workspace/build-swFree-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_GCC_64bit-Release/swFree[0x401344]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7eff198af830]
/home/user/workspace/build-swFree-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_GCC_64bit-Release/swFree[0x4014b9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2098854                            /home/user/workspace/build-swFree-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_GCC_64bit-Release/swFree
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 08:01 2098854                            /home/user/workspace/build-swFree-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_GCC_64bit-Release/swFree
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 2098854                            /home/user/workspace/build-swFree-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_GCC_64bit-Release/swFree
01cdd000-01d1f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7eff10000000-7eff10021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7eff10021000-7eff14000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7eff162bb000-7eff16594000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2752945                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7eff16594000-7eff16602000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529479                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7eff16602000-7eff16802000 ---p 0006e000 08:01 529479                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7eff16802000-7eff16803000 r--p 0006e000 08:01 529479                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7eff16803000-7eff16804000 rw-p 0006f000 08:01 529479                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7eff16804000-7eff1690c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529373                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7eff1690c000-7eff16b0b000 ---p 00108000 08:01 529373                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7eff16b0b000-7eff16b0c000 r--p 00107000 08:01 529373                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7eff16b0c000-7eff16b0d000 rw-p 00108000 08:01 529373                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7eff16b0d000-7eff16c1c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529394                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7eff16c1c000-7eff16e1b000 ---p 0010f000 08:01 529394                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7eff16e1b000-7eff16e1c000 r--p 0010e000 08:01 529394                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7eff16e1c000-7eff16e1d000 rw-p 0010f000 08:01 529394                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
7eff16e1d000-7eff16e1e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
7eff16e1e000-7eff16e1f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2763515                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2                                                                                                                                                 
7eff16e1f000-7eff1701e000 ---p 00001000 08:01 2763515                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2                                                                                                                                                 
7eff1701e000-7eff1701f000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2763515                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2                                                                                                                                                 
7eff1701f000-7eff17020000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 2763515                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2                                                                                                                                                 
7eff17020000-7eff17023000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529264                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff17023000-7eff17222000 ---p 00003000 08:01 529264                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff17222000-7eff17223000 r--p 00002000 08:01 529264                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff17223000-7eff17224000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 529264                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff17224000-7eff1723d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529327                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff1723d000-7eff1743c000 ---p 00019000 08:01 529327                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff1743c000-7eff1743d000 r--p 00018000 08:01 529327                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff1743d000-7eff1743e000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 529327                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff1743e000-7eff18c21000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2379568                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                     
7eff18c21000-7eff18e20000 ---p 017e3000 08:01 2379568                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                     
7eff18e20000-7eff18e21000 r--p 017e2000 08:01 2379568                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                     
7eff18e21000-7eff18fc6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2379575                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                       
7eff18fc6000-7eff191c6000 ---p 001a5000 08:01 2379575                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                       
7eff191c6000-7eff191d6000 r--p 001a5000 08:01 2379575                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                       
7eff191d6000-7eff191d7000 rw-p 001b5000 08:01 2379575                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                       
7eff191d7000-7eff191d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
7eff191d9000-7eff19462000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2379569                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                     
7eff19462000-7eff19661000 ---p 00289000 08:01 2379569                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                     
7eff19661000-7eff1966f000 r--p 00288000 08:01 2379569                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                     
7eff1966f000-7eff19671000 rw-p 00296000 08:01 2379569                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56.1                                                                                                                                                     
7eff19671000-7eff19672000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
7eff19672000-7eff1968a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529099                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                             
7eff1968a000-7eff19889000 ---p 00018000 08:01 529099                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                             
7eff19889000-7eff1988a000 r--p 00017000 08:01 529099                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                             
7eff1988a000-7eff1988b000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 529099                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                             
7eff1988b000-7eff1988f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
7eff1988f000-7eff19a4f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529417                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                                   
7eff19a4f000-7eff19c4f000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 529417                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                                   
7eff19c4f000-7eff19c53000 r--p 001c0000 08:01 529417                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                                   
7eff19c53000-7eff19c55000 rw-p 001c4000 08:01 529417                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so                                                                                                                                                                   
7eff19c55000-7eff19c59000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
7eff19c59000-7eff19c6f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529390                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff19c6f000-7eff19e6e000 ---p 00016000 08:01 529390                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff19e6e000-7eff19e6f000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 529390                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1                                                                                                                                                                  
7eff19e6f000-7eff19fe1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2764170                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21                                                                                                                                                        
7eff19fe1000-7eff1a1e1000 ---p 00172000 08:01 2764170                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21                                                                                                                                                        
7eff1a1e1000-7eff1a1eb000 r--p 00172000 08:01 2764170                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7eff1a1eb000-7eff1a1ed000 rw-p 0017c000 08:01 2764170                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7eff1a1ed000-7eff1a1f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7eff1a1f1000-7eff1a71b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2380819                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.9.1
7eff1a71b000-7eff1a91a000 ---p 0052a000 08:01 2380819                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.9.1
7eff1a91a000-7eff1a926000 r--p 00529000 08:01 2380819                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.9.1
7eff1a926000-7eff1a928000 rw-p 00535000 08:01 2380819                    /opt/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.9.1
7eff1a928000-7eff1a92b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7eff1a92b000-7eff1a951000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524312                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7eff1ab21000-7eff1ab2b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7eff1ab4d000-7eff1ab50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7eff1ab50000-7eff1ab51000 r--p 00025000 08:01 524312                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7eff1ab51000-7eff1ab52000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 524312                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7eff1ab52000-7eff1ab53000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe006ae000-7ffe006cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe006e2000-7ffe006e4000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffe006e4000-7ffe006e6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

The workaround I've figured out was the following:

```
char encrypted[ textUtf8.size() + 1 ];
```

However, I confess that I don't know why it worked. Could someone explain it?

Is there any better solution?

Comment: another strange situation is that the function works nicely if I insert a qDebug() << srcString; right after it's declaration/initialization. I don't know why either

Comment: you have some memory corruption going on in your code. it is difficult to say what causes it without knowing exactly how the sizes are calculated in your functions. Pay attention that the string requires 1 character more than its length to keep '\0' at the end. It lo0ks like you are forgetting to add it to the end of your encrypted string (in a non-encrypted manner),. Run a memory checking tool and/or debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that data in the QByteArray returned by `text.toUtf8()` is not NUL-terminated, and strcpy() expects a NUL-terminated string... since it doesn't get one, it will happily keep copying extra garbage-bytes past the end of your `encrypted` array until it finally does encounter a zero-byte somewhere, and corrupt your stack, which leads to the crash when the function returns.

Also, your `encrypted` array is not large enough to hold the NUL byte that `strcpy()` wants to place in it.

A fix would be something like this:

```
char encrypted[ textUtf8.size() + 1 ];   // +1 to hold the NUL terminator byte
memcpy(encrypted, srcString, textUtf8.size() );
encrypted[textUtf8.size()] = '\0';  // place NUL-terminator byte
[...]
```

Also, a portability note: dynamically-sized arrays [aren't part of the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), so your declaring `char encrypted[ textUtf8.size() + 1];` is working for you only because your compiler includes a non-standard extension to enable that.  If you want your code to be portable (as all self-respecting Qt code should be ;)), you may want to use a std::vector or other similar higher-level mechanism instead of a dynamically-sized array.

Answer (score 1):

char encrypted[ textUtf8.size() + 1 ];

Because of size we have to use a null character to terminate a string array

For example try this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char textUtf8[5] ="hello";  


}
```

You will see warning *"Initializer string for char array is too long"*